# Camera Operation UI testing with Espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, integration-testing, android-testing, android-espresso

I need to automate my UI testing for following operation with espresso test project.

Operation:

Click a button that opens my phone camera. Capture Image, and save the image in sdcard storage. Also update a small image view on the screen when done.

App works fine but with all other operations and similar type of above operation it becomes a time consuming process to test it manually again and again.

Comment: With Espresso you only can test activities inside your application. Camera app cannot be instrumented. Try UI Automator instead: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

Answer (score 12):

I was working with similar problem
and found best available solution at below link
[Camera UI test](https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Espresso)

```
// CameraActivityInstrumentationTest.java
public class CameraActivityInstrumentationTest {

    // IntentsTestRule is an extension of ActivityTestRule. IntentsTestRule sets up Espresso-Intents
    // before each Test is executed to allow stubbing and validation of intents.
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<CameraActivity> intentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(CameraActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void validateCameraScenario() {
        // Create a bitmap we can use for our simulated camera image
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        // Build a result to return from the Camera app
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.putExtra("data", icon);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);

        // Stub out the Camera. When an intent is sent to the Camera, this tells Espresso to respond 
        // with the ActivityResult we just created
        intending(toPackage("com.android.camera2")).respondWith(result);

        // Now that we have the stub in place, click on the button in our app that launches into the Camera
        onView(withId(R.id.btnTakePicture)).perform(click());

        // We can also validate that an intent resolving to the "camera" activity has been sent out by our app
        intended(toPackage("com.android.camera2"));

        // ... additional test steps and validation ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Some devices, like SAMSUNG Galaxy S8 have "com.sec.android.app.camera" package name of it's camera app. This soluttion doesn't work in that device is it?

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the need, you can use the new Espresso-Intent that mocks the activity result that you can use to test this flow.  [See the sample from Android Testing](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample)

Comment: Just a correction, the correct link is now https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided an example on this camera problem, which they show how to stub an camera intent, launch camera, and test if image is get from stub intent, and display on imageView.

```
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<ImageViewerActivity> mIntentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(
     ImageViewerActivity.class);

@Before
public void stubCameraIntent() {
    ActivityResult result = createImageCaptureActivityResultStub();

    // Stub the Intent.
    intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(result);
}

@Test
public void takePhoto_drawableIsApplied() {
    // Check that the ImageView doesn't have a drawable applied.
    onView(withId(R.id.imageView)).check(matches(not(hasDrawable())));

    // Click on the button that will trigger the stubbed intent.
    onView(withId(R.id.button_take_photo)).perform(click());

    // With no user interaction, the ImageView will have a drawable.
    onView(withId(R.id.imageView)).check(matches(hasDrawable()));
}

private ActivityResult createImageCaptureActivityResultStub() {
    // Put the drawable in a bundle.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(ImageViewerActivity.KEY_IMAGE_DATA, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            mIntentsRule.getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    // Create the Intent that will include the bundle.
    Intent resultData = new Intent();
    resultData.putExtras(bundle);

    // Create the ActivityResult with the Intent.
    return new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
}
```

Check this link for more detail [IntentsAdvancedsample](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsAdvancedSample)

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the solutions worked out of the box but the following did. It's a combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444025/1680301) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869418/espresso-intent-test-failing#comment86203078_38045379).

Without calling `Intents.init()` my test would fail with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.test.espresso.intent.OngoingStubbing androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntending(org.hamcrest.Matcher)' on a null object reference
```

Complete solution:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    Intents.init()
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    Intents.release()
}

@Test
fun testCameraIntent() {
    // Build an ActivityResult that will return from the camera app and set your extras (if any).
    val resultData = Intent()
    resultData.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "test.file.url")
    val result = Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData)

    // Mock the camera response. Now whenever an intent is sent to the camera, Espresso will respond with the result we pass here.
    intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(result)

    // Now click on the button in your app that launches the camera. 
    onView(withId(R.id.button_camera)).perform(click());

    // Optionally, we can also verify that the intent to the camera has actually been sent from out.
    intended(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE))

    // At this point the onActivityResult() has been called so verify that whatever view is supposed to be displayed is indeed displayed.
    onView(withId(R.id.some_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))        
}
```