# Espresso intent test failing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm learning android instrumentation testing with espresso. I have an app which has a drawer menu and there is a menu called About. I was testing click on that menu item and contents of activity.

testfunction:

```
  @Test
public void testNavigationDrawerAboutMenu() {
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout))
            .perform(DrawerActions.open()); //open drawer
    onView(withText("About")).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.aboutsptemail)).check(matches(withText(R.string.screen_about_support_email)));
    onView(withId(R.id.aboutcpright)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.aboutprivacy)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.abouttermsconditions)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.aboutsptemail)).perform(click());
}
```

now the last textview has weblink embedded in it. so when you click on it, it opens the link(www.support.com) in  a web view within the app. I want to test this functionality. so I tried this:

```
intended(hasComponent(WebViewActivity.class.getName())); //check if webview called on supportEmail link click
```

but test fails with this error trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.test.espresso.intent.OngoingStubbing android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntending(org.hamcrest.Matcher)' on a null object reference
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intending(Intents.java:155)
at com.ScanBuy.SmartLabel.NavigationDrawerActivityTests.testNavigationDrawerAboutMenu(NavigationDrawerActivityTests.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
```

I have also tried resolve by idling the resources before checking for intent. But didn't work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by using `IntentsTestRule` instead of `ActivityTestRule`. `IntentsTestRule` is a subclass of `ActivityTestRule`. Set up your `@Rule` which creates the activity like so:

```
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> mActivity = new IntentsTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class) {
    @Override
    protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
        ...
    }
};
```

> See the following project for more information:
>   https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample

Comment: ya. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Declaring this rule calls `init()` and `release()` internally but If you don't want to declare `IntentsTestRule` then you will have to call `Intents.init()` explicitly in your code which will make your code run without any error.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a custom `ActivityTestRule`, you can add the proper `Intents.init(), Intents.release()` calls:

```
@Override
protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
    Intents.init();
    super.afterActivityLaunched();
}

@Override
protected void afterActivityFinished() {
    super.afterActivityFinished();
    Intents.release();
}
```

Comment: Is this preferable to using **IntentsTestRule**?

Comment: It's actually the same thing. If you already have a custom ActivityTestRule or you want to enable this feature dinamically it makes sense to use this approach, otherwise just use the IntentsTestRule.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, however, switching to `IntentsTestRule` did not work, too. So I switch back to `ActivityTestRule` and called `Intents.init()` before and `Intents.release()` after the test which sent the Intent.

For more information please see this [reference](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/06/11/testing-for-android-intents-using-espresso).

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using `IntentsTestRule` which is now `@deprecated` in java, you should use the recommended `activityScenarioRule` like so:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
class YourActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
        val activityScenario = activityScenarioRule<YourActivity>()

    @Before
        fun setUp() {
            launchActivity<YourActivity>()
            Intents.init()
        }
    
        @After
        fun tearDown() {
            Intents.release()
        }

    @Test
        fun should_goBackTo_MainActivity_onBackButton_click() {

            onView(withId(R.id.goBackBtn)).perform(click())
            intended(hasComponent(hasShortClassName(".MainActivity")))
        }
}
```

Don't forget adding this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
testOptions {
unitTests {
includeAndroidResources = true
}
}
// testing
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.1-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'   
//for the activityScenarioRule syntax to work in kotlin,
//We add the ktx version of androidx.test.ext:junit
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: You don't need to manually launch your activity if you are using `ActivityScenarioRule`.