# Intending return null (or it has null argument)?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have no idea why "intending" in the following code returns null. I just copied the code from here: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html

**The exception is**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.test.espresso.intent.OngoingStubbing android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntending(org.hamcrest.Matcher)' on a null object reference
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intending(Intents.java:155)
at GsonActivityTest.ensureHandleActivityResultCorrectly(GsonActivityTest.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:257)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
```

**The code is**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.activity.GsonActivity;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intending;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.toPackage;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class GsonActivityTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<GsonActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(GsonActivity.class);

@Test
public void ensureHandleActivityResultCorrectly() {
    // Build a result to return when a particular activity is launched.
    Intent resultData = new Intent();
    String phoneNumber = "123-345-6789";
    resultData.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);

    // Set up result stubbing when an intent sent to "contacts" is seen.
    intending(toPackage("com.android.contacts")).respondWith(result);

    // User action that results in "contacts" activity being launched.
    // Launching activity expects phoneNumber to be returned and displays it on the screen.
    onView(withId(R.id.button8)).perform(click());

    // Assert that data we set up above is shown.
    onView(withId(R.id.editText)).check(matches(withText(phoneNumber)));
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Espresso intent test failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869418/espresso-intent-test-failing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `IntentsTestRule` instead of `ActivityTestRule`

Comment: Thanks. I am a little annoyed that Google states this in one line of texts instead in its sample code. Easy to miss.